# Redis RPUSH - specific return value semantics

Tags: redis, atomic

Redis RPUSH [docs here](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) suggest that the return value of `RPUSH` is `the length of the list after the push operation.`

However, what's not clear to me is:

1. Is the result of `RPUSH` the length of the list after the push operation *atomically*, (so the result is definitely the index of the last item just added by `RPUSH`) or...
2. Is it possible other `RPUSH` operations from concurrent Redis clients could have executed before the `RPUSH` returns, so that you are indeed getting the new length of the list, but that length includes elements from other `RPUSH` commands?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, Redis is single-threaded so it cannot start servicing another request from another client until it has completely finished servicing the first RPUSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is atomic, so the result of the `RPUSH` is indeed the length of the list after the operation.

However, by the time you get the result on the *client*, the list could have changed in arbitrary ways, since other clients could have pushed items, popped items, etc. So that return value really doesn't tell you anything about the state of the list by the time that you receive it on the client.

If it's important to you that the return value match the state of the list, then that implies that you have a *sequence* of operations that you want to be atomic, in which case you can use Redis' transaction facilities. For example, if you performed the `RPUSH` in a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval), you could be sure that the return value represented the state of the list, since the entire script would execute as a single atomic operation.